# Distance points between frames in motion tracking

Tags: tracking

I am learning how to track points in Blender and was wondering if it is possible to get the distance a point travels when tracking points.
Blender shows a line with 'knots in each frame to show its trajectory but I would like to know if it is possible to get the value of that distance. Would a python interface be needed for this?

[image]

Comment: Most likely you need to create a python script to get the coordinates in pixels and do the math from there.

Comment: Here's a script that saves motion tack data to SCV files: https://gist.github.com/groakat/e7d8394d57fd4d3fe016 Note that you need to edit the script to have the output in a folder and file of your choosing.

Comment: This works amazingly well. I just wanted to ask, however, how does the filing system work because I had to run it by just printing everything.

'proj_folder = os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath('//'))' just doesn't  find anything

In any case thank you so much. This code is perfect. Can you make it an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: Thank you @susu I have made yours the default answer. I also found what the problem with the previous code was:
"Returns the absolute path relative to the current blend file using the “//” prefix."
I had not saved the current scene so had no 'current blend file'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done with a script.

(modified from this [Source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5663418))

The script outputs a csv file with the coordinates for each tracker.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import bpy
D = bpy.data

outputFolder= "/set/your/output/directory/here"

printFrameNums = False # include frame numbers in the csv file
relativeCoords = False # marker coords will be relative to the dimensions of the clip

f2=open('export-markers.log', 'w')
print('First line test', file=f2)
for clip in D.movieclips:
    print('clip {0} found\n'.format(clip.name), file=f2)
    width=clip.size[0]
    height=clip.size[1]
    for ob in clip.tracking.objects:
        print('object {0} found\n'.format(ob.name), file=f2)
        for track in ob.tracks:
            print('track {0} found\n'.format(track.name), file=f2)
            fn = outputFolder+'{0}_{1}_tr_{2}.csv'.format(clip.name.split('.')[0], ob.name, track.name)
            with open(fn, 'w') as f:
                framenum = 0
                while framenum < clip.frame_duration:
                    markerAtFrame = track.markers.find_frame(framenum)
                    if markerAtFrame:
                        coords = markerAtFrame.co.xy
                        if relativeCoords:
                            if printFrameNums:
                                print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(framenum, coords[0], coords[1]), file=f)
                            else:
                                print('{0},{1}'.format(coords[0], coords[1]), file=f)
                        else:
                            if printFrameNums:
                                print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(framenum, coords[0]*width, coords[1]*height), file=f)
                            else:
                                print('{0},{1}'.format(coords[0]*width, coords[1]*height), file=f)

                    framenum += 1
f2.close()
```

Pay attention to the units used.

The script will output coordinates in pixels, where 0,0 is at the bottom left of the frame.

To use a float values, where the frame has coordinates 0 to 1, change `relativeCoords = True`

To include the frame number as part of the set, use `printFrameNums = True`